# Как в js проверить свойство на пренадлежность к конкретному типу?

Tags: javascript

Есть свойство

```
var array = [];
```

Как я могу проверить, что свойство **array** является типом Array?
Наверняка способ не один и если можно, перечислите их все.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этого вполне достаточно

```
function is_array (a) {
    return (typeof a == "object") && (a instanceof Array);
}
```

Comment: @mountpoint: Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

1. Array.isArray(a)
2. a && (a instanceof Array)
3. a && (a.constructor === Array)
4. Object.prototype.toString.call(a) === '[object Array]'
5. a && ((a.length > 0) && ('0' in a) || a.length === 0 && !('0' in a))

Вроде всё.